# Can I overload a type-bound procedure based on the number of arguments?

Tags: oop, fortran, gfortran

I'm working on an aerodynamics code (source code [here](https://github.com/usuaero/MFTran)) using good old Fortran. Part of the initialization is reading in a file which contains information on a surface mesh, basically a set of triangular or quadrilateral panels making up the surface. I'd like to describe both quadrilateral and triangular panels using a single type `panel`. To do that, I've written two initialization functions `panel_init_3` and `panel_init_4` which will load the data into the type based on how many vertices the panel has. I'd like to bind these to my `panel` type and overload them based on the number of arguments (i.e. if it gets passed an integer and 3 vertex objects, then `panel_init_3` gets called and similarly for 4 vertex objects.

Here is the source code for the type:

```
module panel_mod

    use linked_list_mod
    use vertex_mod

    implicit none


    type panel
        ! A panel with an arbitrary number of sides

        integer :: N ! Number of sides/vertices
        type(vertex_pointer),dimension(:),allocatable :: vertices
        real,dimension(3) :: n_hat ! Normal vector
        real :: A ! Surface area

        contains

            procedure :: init => panel_init_3, panel_init_4
            procedure :: calc_area => panel_calc_area
            procedure :: calc_normal => panel_calc_area

    end type panel

    
contains


    subroutine panel_init_3(this, v1, v2, v3)
        ! Initializes a 3-panel

        implicit none

        class(panel),intent(inout) :: this
        type(vertex),intent(in),target :: v1, v2, v3

        ! Set number of sides
        this%N = 3

        ! Allocate vertex array
        allocate(this%vertices(this%N))

        ! Store info
        this%vertices(1)%ptr => v1
        this%vertices(2)%ptr => v2
        this%vertices(3)%ptr => v3

        ! Calculate normal vec

        ! Calculate area

    end subroutine panel_init_3


    subroutine panel_init_4(this, v1, v2, v3, v4)
        ! Initializes a panel with 4 sides

        implicit none

        class(panel),intent(inout) :: this
        type(vertex),intent(in),target :: v1, v2, v3, v4
        
        ! Set number of sides
        this%N = 4

        ! Allocate vertex array
        allocate(this%vertices(this%N))

        ! Store info
        this%vertices(1)%ptr => v1
        this%vertices(2)%ptr => v2
        this%vertices(3)%ptr => v3
        this%vertices(4)%ptr => v4

        ! Calculate normal vector

        ! Calculate area

    end subroutine panel_init_4


    subroutine panel_calc_area(this)

        implicit none

        class(panel),intent(inout) :: this

    end subroutine panel_calc_area


    subroutine panel_calc_normal(this)

        implicit none

        class(panel),intent(inout) :: this

    end subroutine panel_calc_normal

    
end module panel_mod
```

This module compiles fine. But, when it gets used here

```
...
! Initialize triangular panel
if (N == 3) then
   call panels(i)%init(vertices(i1+1), vertices(i2+1), vertices(i3+1)) ! Need +1 because VTK is 0-indexed

! Initialize quadrilateral panel
else
   call panels(i)%init(vertices(i1+1), vertices(i2+1), vertices(i3+1), vertices(i4+1))
end if
...
```

I get the compiler message

```
   70 |                     call panels(i)%init(vertices(i1+1), vertices(i2+1), vertices(i3+1), vertices(i4+1))
      |                                                                                                       1
Error: More actual than formal arguments in procedure call at (1)
```

Am I reaching beyond the capabilities of Fortran, or is there a way to do this? I realize I could do this all without binding and overloading, but I like how clean it'd be. I am using gfortran 9.3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to define `init` as a generic procedure (binding) with those other two being the specific procedures (bindings)

```
   contains

        procedure :: panel_init_3
        procedure :: panel_init_4
        generic :: init => panel_init_3, panel_init_4
```

It is quite similar to what is normally done with normal procedures using named `interface` blocks when you do

```
interface generic_init
  procedure specific_init_3
  procedure specific_init_4
end interface
```

Answer (score 5):

In a type-bound procedure declaration statement it's possible to declare more than one binding name in a list, so we can have

```
type mytype
contains
  procedure :: binding1, binding2
end type
```

giving the two binding names.  These are individual bindings.  These binding names resolve to procedures with the same name as each.  That is, we can write this as

```
type mytype
contains
  procedure :: binding1 => binding1, binding2 => binding2
end type
```

The list nature of the binding names is such that

```
type mytype
contains
  procedure :: binding => binding1, binding2
end type
```

has the items in the list `binding=>binding1` and `binding2`. This has effect
like

```
type mytype
contains
  procedure :: binding => binding1, binding2 => binding2
end type
```

That is, we still have two distinct binding names each binding to a single procedure.

We do not have a generic `binding` binding name with specific procedures `binding1` and `binding2`.  For that, we'd need a generic explicitly created:

```
type mytype
contains
  procedure :: binding1, binding2
  generic :: binding => binding1, binding2
end type
```

In this generic statement, the list has `binding1` and `binding2` as items as specifics for the generic `binding`.  Precise syntax rules for these lists/statements is given in Fortran 2018 7.5.5.